# Trouble replacing Chr(160) with VBA in excel

Tags: vba, special-characters

I have been receiving excel files for awhile that are usually plagued with the special character alt+0160 after the accounts. I usually just manually replace it in excel but recently I've grown lazy and want to replace it using my VBA script. This script is used to insert the needed columns into our database:

```
Sub insert()

    Dim sSql As String
    Dim db As New ADODB.Connection 'Go to Tools, References and turn on ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library
    db.Open "DSN=XXXX;uid=XXXX;pwd=XXXX" 'INSERT ORACLE NAME AND PASSWORD

    For i = 2 To 92 'Change Rows where it starts and ends

            strAccount = Replace(Trim(Range("a" & i).Text), Chr(160), "")

            If IsNumeric(strAccount) Then
                    While Len(strAccount) < 8
                            strAccount = "0" & strAccount
                    Wend
            Else
                    strAccount = UCase(strAccount)
            End If

    sSql = "insert into XXXXX ("
    sSql = sSql & "    BATCH_ID"
    sSql = sSql & "  , ACCOUNT "
    sSql = sSql & "  , ATTORNEY_ID"
    sSql = sSql & "  , ORG_ID"
    sSql = sSql & "  , TRANSACTION_DATE"
    sSql = sSql & "  , DATE_INSERTED"
    sSql = sSql & "  , TRANSACTION_CODE"
    sSql = sSql & "  , AMOUNT"
    sSql = sSql & "  , DESCRIPTION"
    sSql = sSql & "  , DEBTOR_SSN"

    sSql = sSql & ") VALUES ("
    sSql = sSql & "    (SELECT MAX(BATCH_ID) FROM XXXX)"
    sSql = sSql & "  , '" & strAccount & "'"
    sSql = sSql & "  , (SELECT ATTY_ID FROM XXXX WHERE BATCH_ID = (SELECT MAX(BATCH_ID) FROM XXXXX))"
    sSql = sSql & "  , (SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID FROM XXXX WHERE BATCH_ID = (SELECT MAX(BATCH_ID) FROM XXXXX))"
    sSql = sSql & "  , TO_DATE ('" & Trim(Range("B" & i).Text) & "', 'MM/DD/YYYY') "
    sSql = sSql & "  , SYSDATE"
    sSql = sSql & "  , '" & Trim(Range("D" & i).Text) & "'" 'CHANGE TO COLUMN TRANSACTION CODE IS IN
    sSql = sSql & "  , '" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Trim(Range("C" & i).Text), "$", ""), ",", ""), ")", ""), "(", "") & "'"
    sSql = sSql & "  , '" & Replace(Trim(Range("H" & i).Text), "'", "''") & "'"
    sSql = sSql & "  , '" & Replace(Replace(Trim(Range("F" & i).Text), " ", ""), "-", "") & "'"

    sSql = sSql & ")"


    db.Execute sSql

    DoEvents
    Debug.Print i

    Next i
End Sub
```

Now I did some research and found out that to replace these characters you use Chr(160). I have used that in my `Replace` but it does not seem to be doing the trick, the accounts still get uploaded with those terrible special characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve it. I created a function to help with the situation and it now works.

```
Function CleanText(strText As String) As String
    If strText = "" Then
        CleanText = ""
    Else
        strText = Replace(strText, "'", "''")
        strText = Replace(strText, " ", "")
        strText = Replace(strText, vbTab, " ")
        strText = Replace(strText, vbCrLf, " ")
        strText = Replace(strText, Chr(160), "")
        CleanText = strText
    End If
End Function
```