# Same value in 2 files are different when compared VBA

Tags: string, vba, comparison

I'm trying to compared 2 different excel files that contain same fields sometimes.
When I find it (by watch view) the vba say they are different...

```
Dim ctrl As Integer
Sub btnCheck_Click()
    Dim lot As Workbook, pr As Workbook, this As Workbook
    Dim a As Variant, b As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim passed As Boolean

Set this = Application.ThisWorkbook
this.Worksheets(1).Range("C5:J1000").ClearContents

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

a = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "A.xlsx"
Set lot = Application.Workbooks.Open(a, False, False)

b = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "B.xls"
Set pr = Application.Workbooks.Open(b, False, False)

i = 2
x = 2
lin = 2
Do Until lot.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value = ""
    passed = False
    j = 2
    Do Until pr.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & j).Value = ""
        If lot.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = pr.Worksheets(1).Range("C" & j).Value Then
            passed = True
            this.Worksheets(1).Range("D" & x).Value = "ok"
            x = x + 2
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
   i = i + 1
Loop
lot.Close True
Set lot = Nothing

pr.Close True
Set pr = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True   

End Sub

Function CleanStr(ByVal str As String)
CleanStr = Replace(str, Chr$(32), "")
End Function
```

The files A and B are linked at the comments bellow.

Comment: can you include the whole loop?

Comment: Does one of them contain two trailing spaces rather than one?

Comment: The string lenghts is the same

Comment: I used `Replace(srt, " ", "")` seems like content of file B is protected

Comment: where is that `srt` in your code?

Comment: Maybe specify the compare method? `StrComp(sa, sb, vbTextCompare)` for case-insensitive or `StrComp(sa, sb, vbBinaryCompare)` for case-sensitive. You can also add `Trim` to your values if you want to get rid of leading/trailing spaces. Eg: `StrComp(Trim(sa), Trim(sb), vbBinaryCompare)`

Comment: `str` is a argument for a Function created

Comment: you'd better post a fully functional code, relevant for the current issue only

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxlNqIVLu5AZMWg2ZVcxajYzZDg) please see here all content files where A2 and B3 are same value but not for StrComp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A and B are not the same. One ends in a space (ASCII 32) while the other ends in a non-breaking space (ASCII 160). Invisible is invisible to our eyes, but to a computer, ASCII(32)<>ASCII(160)

You can verify this by adding this function to your macro:

```
Function strings2ascii(ByVal str1 As String, str2 As String)
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim intStrLen As Integer
    Dim strResult As String

    If Len(str1) > Len(str2) Then
        intStrLen = Len(str1)
    Else
        intStrLen = Len(str2)
    End If

    For x = 1 To Len(str1)
        strResult = strResult & Asc(Mid(str1, x, 1)) & ":" & Asc(Mid(str2, x, 1)) & vbCrLf
    Next

    MsgBox strResult
End Function
```

Now call this function in your loop:

```
    Do Until pr.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & j).Value = ""
        strings2ascii lot.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value, pr.Worksheets(1).Range("C" & j).Value
        If lot.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = pr.Worksheets(1).Range("C" & j).Value Then
```

You will immediately see that they never match because they are not the same. Here is a similar SO post regarding ASCII 160 errors: [Trouble replacing Chr(160) with VBA in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620293/trouble-replacing-chr160-with-vba-in-excel)

Comment: ASCII has 128 codepoints numbered from 0 to 127. Despite its name `Asc` returns the ANSI codepoint, using the default ANSI code page (character set and encoding). But since strings contain UTF-16 encoded Unicode, you might consider `AscW` instead. That way you don't have depend on which ANSI code page the code runs under.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will answer the question but that can't stand in a comment :)

I would say that some cells contains invisible chars that arent spaces.

Here's a recursive function that remove them from a string :

```
Function CleanString(StrIn As String) As String
    ' "Cleans" a string by removing embedded control (non-printable)
    ' characters, including carriage returns and linefeeds.
    ' Does not remove special characters like symbols, international
    ' characters, etc. This function runs recursively, each call
    ' removing one embedded character

    Dim iCh As Integer
    CleanString = StrIn

    For iCh = 1 To Len(StrIn)
        If Asc(Mid(StrIn, iCh, 1)) < 32 Then
            'remove special character
            CleanString = Left(StrIn, iCh - 1) & CleanString(Mid(StrIn, iCh + 1))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iCh

End Function
```

Give it a try like this :

```
Do Until b.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & j).Value = ""
    sa = CleanString(a.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value)
    sb = CleanString(b.Worksheets(1).Range("C" & j).Value)
    oa = CleanString(a.Worksheets(1).Range("E" & i).Value)
    ob = CleanString(b.Worksheets(1).Range("F" & j).Value)
        If StrComp(sa, sb) = 0 And StrComp(oa, ob) = 0 Then
            Passed = True
```

Comment: does not work, one file extension is .xls and other is .xlsx

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxlNqIVLu5AZMWg2ZVcxajYzZDg) please see here all content files where A2 and B3 are same value but not for StrComp